# Reading nested json as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

Trying to read a nested json into as a pandas dataframe but keep getting the error message

```
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

This is what I have tried:

```
import json
file = json.load(open('../Datasets/MathNYC.json'))
file = pd.DataFrame(file)
```

I have also tried using json_normalize and instead get a single row of data as opposed to multiple rows of data

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.io.json.json_normalize(file))
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
{'meta': {'view': {'id': 'x4ai-kstz',
   'name': '2013-2017 School Math Results - Gender',
   'averageRating': 0,
   'category': 'Education',
   'createdAt': 1506355113,
   'displayType': 'table',
   'downloadCount': 1106,
   'hideFromCatalog': False,
   'hideFromDataJson': False,
   'indexUpdatedAt': 1536602847,
   'locale': 'en_US',
   'newBackend': True,
   'numberOfComments': 0,
   'oid': 26867540,
   'provenance': 'official',
   'publicationAppendEnabled': False,
   'publicationDate': 1506356065,
   'publicationGroup': 14486436,
   'publicationStage': 'published',
   'rowClass': '',
   'rowsUpdatedAt': 1506355132,
   'rowsUpdatedBy': 'fn2b-3u6b',
   'tableId': 14486436,
   'totalTimesRated': 0,
   'viewCount': 370,
   'viewLastModified': 1549924017,
   'viewType': 'tabular',
   'approvals': [{'reviewedAt': 1506356065,
     'reviewedAutomatically': True,
     'state': 'approved',
     'submissionId': 1068765,
     'submissionObject': 'public_audience_request',
     'submissionOutcome': 'change_audience',
     'submittedAt': 1506356065,
     'workflowId': 2285,
     'submissionDetails': {'permissionType': 'READ'},
     'submissionOutcomeApplication': {'failureCount': 0, 'status': 'success'},
     'submitter': {'id': 'fn2b-3u6b', 'displayName': 'Jose Beiro'}}],
   'columns': [{'id': -1,
     'name': 'sid',
     'dataTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'fieldName': ':sid',
     'position': 0,
     'renderTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'format': {},
     'flags': ['hidden']},
    {'id': -1,
     'name': 'id',
     'dataTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'fieldName': ':id',
     'position': 0,
     'renderTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'format': {},
     'flags': ['hidden']},
    {'id': -1,
     'name': 'position',
     'dataTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'fieldName': ':position',
     'position': 0,
     'renderTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'format': {},
     'flags': ['hidden']},
    {'id': -1,
     'name': 'created_at',
     'dataTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'fieldName': ':created_at',
     'position': 0,
     'renderTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'format': {},
     'flags': ['hidden']},
    {'id': -1,
     'name': 'created_meta',
     'dataTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'fieldName': ':created_meta',
     'position': 0,
     'renderTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'format': {},
     'flags': ['hidden']},
    {'id': -1,
     'name': 'updated_at',
     'dataTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'fieldName': ':updated_at',
     'position': 0,
     'renderTypeName': 'meta_data',
     'format': {},
     'flags': ['hidden']}]}}}
```

Comment: What result would you expect?

Comment: Can you add another row to your example, so we can see where does `json.normalize` give a different result than desired? your example has a single row anyway, if I understand correctly and id is the row index. Also, I can't reproduce the error with this example (maybe it's because there's only one row, or some other reason that I don't see right now).